# Error: `LngLatLike` al cargar mapa Mapbox

Tags: javascript, ajax, mapbox

sinceramente no se de donde puede venir el error, modifiqué cosas sobre un form y dejó de funcionar la llamada hacia ajax

me manda este error

```
Error: `LngLatLike` argument must be specified as a LngLat instance, an object {lng: <lng>, lat: <lat>}, an object {lon: <lng>, lat: <lat>}, or an array of [<lng>, <lat>]
```

en este trozo de codigo

```
function llamarDatos() {
    return axios.post('{{ route('guest.traer-todo') }}', $('#formFiltros').serialize());
}
llamarDatos()
    .then(x => {
        estacionamientos = {
            type: "FeatureCollection",
            features: []
        };
        x.data.forEach(item => {
            estacionamientos.features.push({
                type: 'Feature',
                properties: {
                    id_estacionamiento: item.id_estacionamiento,
                    numero: item.numero,
                    direccion: item.direccion,
                    descripcion: item.descripcion,
                    precio: item.precio,
                    fecha: item.fecha,
                    url: item.url
                },
                geometry: {
                    type: 'Point',
                    coordinates: [item.longitud, item.latitud]
                },
            });
        });
        console.log(estacionamientos);
        // MAPA
        mapboxgl.accessToken =
            'pk.eyJ1IjoiZXN0YWNpb25hdGVjbCIsImEiOiJjanVzbDh5djAyMnh1NDZwbnJ4YTByMWs4In0.PVwQnZ0wHPbWbOiPfFFWBw';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map', // container id
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // stylesheet location
            center:  '[-70.6472400, -33.4726900]' , // starting position [lng, lat]
            zoom: 12, // starting zoom
        });
```

más específicamente en el

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map
```

sinceramente no sé que puede estar pasando y ya he intentado prácticamente todo lo que sé, con el console log verifico que los datos llegan correctamente y aún así no sé que puede ser

Comment: Creo que el problema está en el definición del valor de la propiedad `center`, debería ser `center: [-70.6472400, -33.4726900]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema que tienes es el siguiente:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    // Estás definiendo el valor de la propiedad center como un string
    center:  '[-70.6472400, -33.4726900]',
    zoom: 12, // starting zoom
 });
```

Y debería ser así

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    // Debería ser así, o bien, como te lo dicta el error
    center:  [-70.6472400, -33.4726900],
    zoom: 12, // starting zoom
 });
```